# MDX expression for 'sum of all sales 5 years before and years before that'!

Tags: mdx

I have a variety of calculated members to measure netsales during different periods. Eg:

```
sum([Report Period].[Report Periods].currentmember.lag(49):
   [Report Period].[Report    Periods].currentmember.lag(60),[measures].[netsale])
```

which calculates sum of netsales for periods between 49th and 60th month.

I am not able to figure out how to write an MDX statement to calculate sum of netsales 60 months before (5 years) and the years before that.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the LastPeriods() function?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the .FirstChild operator in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144947.aspx

Depending on how you set up your dimension (is Report Periods your final level?), either FirstChild or a combination of Head( , 1) with Descendants( , ) should do the trick.